# drupal administration access

Tags: drupal

How to give an admin access to the users who have logged in using ldap username and password after authentication. And should we store this $_POST values in drupal database.

Comment: Could you state the question a little bit more clearly. What version of Drupal are you using, how are you using the LDAP authentication.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ldap_integration module after an LDAP user logs in for the first time a full local Drupal user is created for them. Install http://drupal.org/project/adminrole which lets you assign your users, even LDAP users, into an "Admin Role". This module gives all available permissions to users in this role.